# ImageMapster to dynamically show and hide image selection crash

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, mobile-safari, imagemapster

I have an image where I want to dynamically show grey/green/red shaded blocks to highlight different areas of the image. Ie small parts of the image will dynamically shift between shades of grey/green/red.

I've decided to use the jQuery plugin ImageMapster:
http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/

It seems to be a great plugin, and it lets me design imagemaps for an image that I then controll in ImageMapster.

My challenge is that I want to control all the selection from javascript and that I need to change the color of the selected areas between 3 colors and make ImageMapster update the image.

I've tried two methods.

**A.** Change the ImageMapster mapOptions with specific area settings, deselect all areas, select all areas.

```
$('#shape1').mapster('set_options',{areas : newArea});
$('area').mapster('deselect');
$('area').mapster('select');
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/koniak/zo04e3ns/

**B.** For each area, deselect using new area options, select using new area options.

```
$('#shape1').mapster('set',false,value.id, {fillColor: stateOptions[value.state].fillColor});
$('#shape1').mapster('set',true,value.id, {fillColor: stateOptions[value.state].fillColor});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/koniak/evwuvnby/

Both these option causes crashes on iOS Safari and PC Chrome. 
- Option A above takes a little while on Safari and a longer while on Chrome.
- Option B above crashes directly on Safari and after a while on Chrome. (Removing the "select step" removes the error, but the image wont update)

When initially retrieving the page from a web server I get the following error which I don't know if it's related:

```
jquery.imagemapster.js:2047 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of null
p.createCanvasFor @ jquery.imagemapster.js:2047
m.Graphics.createVisibleCanvas @ jquery.imagemapster.js:1841
p.refreshSelections @ jquery.imagemapster.js:2062
m.MapData.removeSelectionFinish @ jquery.imagemapster.js:3378
finishSetForMap @ jquery.imagemapster.js:1472
$.mapster.impl.me.set @ jquery.imagemapster.js:1525
$.mapster.impl.me.deselect @ jquery.imagemapster.js:1430
$.fn.mapster @ jquery.imagemapster.js:834updateCycle @ (index):145nter code here
```

Though everything behaves as planned.

So my questions are:
1. Using ImageMapster is this the best way to force an update (ie deselecting and selecting) or are there other options?
2. What can be causing the bug with ImageMapster (or my code)?

Any input appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This is an "x/y problem".

You don't need imageMapster for this. Instead, try using a canvas element and drawing an image to it, then simply drawing semi-transparent rectangles on top of that image. Note that you would need to redraw the image when a deselect happens.

Comment: Since changes will be happening continuously at different (simultaneous) points of the map, redrawing the complete image would probably be needed at every update interval. I would also need to design an own way to handle the areas instead of using imagemaps. One way to eliminate redraws would be to actually have 4 (!!!) images as sources, one without colors and one each for the shades with every area shaded. Then if an area change, I could just copy the correct source to the canvas.
But what I really want is a plugin to solve this like ImageMapster "almost" does, except for the errors.